# Sanding woods of different hardnesses perfectly flat

Tags: finishing, sanding, hardwood

I'm making a chess board from jatoba and maple.  I made a mistake in my planning stage, and mis-interpretted the max width of my planer.  As such, the board top is now just a bit to wide to go through, so it looks like I'm going to have to hand sand it flat.   The worst ridges between the woods are about 1/10 mm, so not overly bad, but also not non-existent.

The issue is that the two types of wood, jatoba and maple, have different hardnesses (1450 vs 2900), so I'm wondering if I should be worried about using an ROS on this, in respects to uneven removal.   My other option might be to glue a rougher grit paper to a large flat board and use this combined with a lot of elbow grease to smooth it out.   I'm unfortunately not overly experienced in working with these sorts of hardwoods, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you should be concerned about doing this with a random-orbit sander unless the pad is unusually hard. Not using power tools, this sort of work is ideally tackled by planing or scraping, but even scraping (by the usual means) would present some difficulties.

Answer (score 7):

> My other option might be to glue a rougher grit paper to a large flat board and use this combined with a lot of elbow grease to smooth it out.

If you use the right abrasive and the right strategy this basic idea could work well for you, without it being tons of effort (as hand sanding usually is).

You must ensure the abrasive is taut, so it doesn't ruck up as you push back and forth, so it may be necessary to glue it to the substrate.

Also, instead of making one or more large sanding boards you might want to make large sanding blocks instead. Easier to hold and manipulate sanding blocks than the whole board.

Don't use cheap paper here, it's a false economy. It might be worth investing in some 3M Cubitron for this!

**Start coarse**
In general with something like this it's advisable to begin with a coarser grit than you're probably thinking, possibly much coarser. But a very good modern abrasive like Cubitron changes the picture.

**Start by sanding on the diagonals**
Wood is much easier to sand (and plane incidentally) across the grain rather than along it. Not sure if you've alternated the grain direction on your white and black squares as is often done, but if you have the ideal compromise is to sand at 45°.

**Grit progression**
Suggested grit progression for the hand sanding is 60, 100, 150, 240 if using conventional abrasives. If you use Cubitron or something else high-tech you could probably get away with starting at 100.

**Bring out your ROS with finer papers to finish off**
You might consider going to 320 or a little above here, although that's generally finer than you need to sand wood.

**Alternatively, scrape after board has been made flat**
Good results can be had with a well-prepared card scraper, or with the sharp edge of a utility-knife blade or single-edged razor if you don't currently own any card scrapers.